Generate single dataframe using 2 dataframe with different number of rows, combining the columns
we have 2 dataframes with different number of columns and rows. Want to combine both to a single dataframe in *python 3.7
Df1:



c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
c6




abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3



DF2:



s1
s2
s3
s4




34.7
83.9
0
67


35.7
73.5
0
67


44.7
21.4
0
67


67.7
56.1
0
67


90.7
79
0
67


7
21.4
0
67


12
83.9
0
67



Result expected:



c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
c6
s1
s2
s3
s4




abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
34.7
83.9
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
35.7
73.5
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
44.7
21.4
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
67.7
56.1
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
90.7
79
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
7
21.4
0
67


abc
2024-05-02
EOC
12.7
xyz
3
12
83.9
0
67



I have tried using concat with axis=1
 df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
 df_3.loc[:, 'c1':'c6'] = df_3.loc[:, 'c1':'c6'].ffill()

This works with Python 3.9+ but how to handle this in Python 3.7

Do you need df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).ffill() ? Or df1.merge(df2, how='cross') ?

I dont know if merge works on python 3.7, but ffill works for sure: df_concatenated = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) ... columns_to_ffill = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6'] for col in columns_to_ffill:     df_concatenated[col] = df_concatenated[col].fillna(method='ffill')

Is     df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0) available on python 3.7?

it giving reindexing error:
pandas.errors.invalidindexerror: reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects python 3.7

df.merge(df1, how='cross') worked
